# Is there a way to force a type argument to be provided when calling a generic/parameterized method?

Tags: java, generics

Let's say I have a class and method like this:

```java
public class Example {

    private final Map<String, Object> stuff = new HashMap<>();

    public <T> T getValue(String key) {
        return (T) stuff.get(key);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to force someone writing code that calls `getValue()` to explicitly provide a type witness to the method call?

```java
Example example = new Example();
Boolean resultWithParameter    = example.<Boolean>getValue("some_key");
```

What I'd like to do is always require the parameter when calling the method. Is there a way to do that? I know I could always add a `Class` parameter but I was exploring other options.

Comment: That's called a type witness

Comment: Not sure what you're saying.  If you want a certain return type, then you specify the type.  Anytime you use a single type parameter `<T>` like this, it's equivalent to just saying `Object` so you abdicated your chance to require a type by declaring it that way.  Declare it with the type you want instead.

Comment: And I've never heard the term "type witness" before, so I'd appreciate an explanation of that term.

Comment: @markspace [Type Witness in java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932177/type-witness-in-java-generics)

Comment: @markspace From Oracle tutorials https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: I've never heard it called a "type witness" before. I learned something new today.

Comment: Yup, me too actually.  Thanks @Michael

Comment: @Michael But "type witness" is not the official term and is not mentioned anywhere in the Java Language Specification. The JLS calls them "[**type arguments**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5.1)", whether as `List<Integer>` or `example.<Boolean>getValue()` doesn't matter, the `<type, ...>` part is the *type arguments*, similar to `(expr, ...)` being *method arguments*.

Comment: @Andreas I was having a think about this. I think the reason that the JLS omits it is because it has no reason to make the distinction. If the JLS used both terms, there would be the potential for the behaviour to vary between the two. It is therefore preferable to only use the broadest applicable term. In the real world, the term 'type witness' holds additional semantic value because it refers to type arguments used in a specific way. Therefore I don't think it is correct to assert - if it is what you're asserting - that the term is "not official" simply because the JLS doesn't define it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to enforce it. Here is the structure of a method invocation [as defined by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12).

```
MethodInvocation:
  MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
  TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
  TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
ArgumentList:
  Expression {, Expression}
```

Specifically, your example refers to this one

```
Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )

example . <Boolean>       getValue   ( "some_key"     );
```

If you are not familiar with [the notation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4), the most important part is this:

> The syntax `[x]` on the right-hand side of a production denotes zero or
>   one occurrences of x. That is, `x` is an optional symbol

So where `[TypeArguments]` (a type witness) is applicable, it is always optional; there is no way to enforce that it is present.