# Why doesn't Optional.empty().orElse("test") work?

Tags: java, types, option-type

I tried this line while experimenting:

```
String test = Optional.empty().orElse("test");
```

--and to my surprise it gave a type error: `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String.`

Why is that? Looking at the source, `orElse` should just return what's being passed in if the optional is empty, which it is here. So what am I missing? This works fine, on the other hand:

```
String test = Optional.of("me").orElse("test");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is an issue related to generics. If you look at the `empty()` static method, it is a generic method and has a type variable. If you just call `Optional.empty` then the type variable T is taken to be `Object` and you have incompatible types. The Optional is of type `Optional<Object>`, and it will dispense an `Object`, not a `String`. To fix the problem, you have to help the compiler by passing the type parameter explicitly. Here's the fix.

```
String test = Optional.<String> empty().orElse("test");
```

However, if your target type is `Object`, then it would work because `String` is some subtype of `Object`, as shown below.

```
Object test = Optional.empty().orElse("test");
```

Comment: OHHH the `orElse` is using the T from `Optional.empty()` for its return type, not the T from what I pass in to `orElse`, of course not, T is already set at that point....I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

`Optional.empty()` returns an `Optional<Object>`, which you then "fill" with a String. So the return type of `orElse` is already determined to be Object regardless of you having passed in a string as a parameter.

If you want to create an empty `Optional<String>` you can specify the type with:

```
String test = Optional.<String> empty().orElse("Test");
```

Alternatively, if you want automatic typing, you can do it in two steps:

```
Optional<String> opt = Optional.empty();
String test = opt.orElse("test");
```

Comment: What is that syntax called where you use `<String>` in a method call like `Optional.<String> empty()`? I haven't come across it before. I know it's part of the generics system but didn't realize it could be part of a method call in addition to a method signature or variable declaration.

Comment: @temporary_user_name I believe the `<String>` in `Optional.<String>empty()` is called a "type witness".

Comment: @temporary_user_name The "official" name is defined in [JLS #15.12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12): it's called Type Arguments. But many call it type witness. For more history, you can also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030402/829571 (and thanks for the edit).