# What is this Java generics notation before a method called?

Tags: java, generics

I came across some sample code with a generics notation I'm not familiar with:

```
vertx.eventBus().<JsonObject>consumer("sensor.updates", message -> {
  JsonObject json = message.body();
  ...
});
```

Note the "<JsonObject>" before the call to consumer().

I understand what it does, that consumer() takes a generic type T and we're telling the compiler to expect a JsonObject in the second parameter. From the [EventBus.consumer](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/eventbus/EventBus.html#consumer-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.Handler-) docs:

```
<T> MessageConsumer<T> consumer(String address, Handler<Message<T>> handler)
```

I guess I'm just surprised to see unfamiliar generics syntax after using it for many years. Is there a name for this notation, or any non-obvious behavior I need to be aware of?

Comment: It's mentioned in the tutorial here (I'm still looking for an exact answer myself): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: Ah, I think this is it, it's called a *type witness.*  It's used when the type inference system can't distinguish between two or more generic methods and you have to specify which one you want it to use.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html

Comment: The duplicate link also has an answer that explains that type witnesses were more useful in Java 7, but by Java 8 the type inference system was improved and you hardly ever need a type witness anymore.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24932177/5515060

Comment: Thanks @markspace. Type Witness is exactly what I was looking for. I've been writing Java since before generics existed, and it's always somewhat horrifying/pleasing to come across something that makes me say "what the heck is that thing?"

Answer (score -1):

Generally Generics has two types, these are

1. Generics Types
2. Generics Methods

#### Generics Types

You can use type parameters in your class or interface. Generics using in Types are called Generics Types.

```
public interface Container<T> {
    T first();
    T last();
    void add(T data);
    List<T> getAll();
}

public class MyContainer<T> implements Container<T> {
    // Implementations
}
```

#### Generics Methods

Type Parameter can also be defined in a method, and those are called Generics Method. You can define Generics in all methods, such as static and instance methods. The question that you asked is Generics Method.

```
public static <T> void printTwoTimes(T data) {
    // Codes
}
```

By taking type parameter in a method, this method can get type abstraction and can be use with various types in type safe way.

This is an official reference about Generics Methods.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't actually answer the question.