# Why do I need to typecast when using thenComparing in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, casting, comparator

I'm deeply confused by why the first block of code can compile, while the second block of code can't compile.

Can compile

```
        int[][] arr = {{2,2}, {1,2}, {3,4}};
        List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(arr);
        
        // sort by first element
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x[0]));
```

Cannot compile. Error is "Array type expected; found: 'java.lang.Object'"

```
        int[][] arr = {{2,2}, {1,2}, {3,4}};
        List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(arr);

        // sort by first element, then by second element
        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x[0]).thenComparingInt( x -> x[1]));
```

In order to fix the error, I had to do

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> ((int[])x)[0]).thenComparingInt( x -> ((int[])x)[1]));
```

My question is, why I had to typecast if calling `comparingInt` and then `thenComparingInt`, while typecast is not needed if I was only calling `comparingInt`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Very confused by Java 8 Comparator type inference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436871/very-confused-by-java-8-comparator-type-inference)

Answer (score 2):

With just `Comparator.comparingInt`, the compiler can infer that the single generic method call and the desired type should be the same - `Comparator<int[]>`.

The second chained call disrupts the type inference completely. The desired type is still `Comparator<int[]>`, and this is what `thenComparingInt` should return. But the compiler is not (yet?) smart enough to determine what the return type of `Comparator.comparingInt` should be. That's why you get a compiler error.

Your casts work, but you can make it a bit easier by telling the compiler what generic type to use for `Comparator.comparingInt`. Then, `thenComparingInt` continues from that generic type.

There are two ways I can think of:

1. `list.sort(Comparator.<int[]>comparingInt(x -> x[0]).thenComparingInt(x -> x[1]))`
2. `list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt((int[] x) -> x[0]).thenComparingInt(x -> x[1]))`

In the first case, you just tell the compiler "the generic type for the method is `int[]`". In the second case, you let the compiler infer it from the argument, which you tell the compiler is a `Function<int[], int>` by specifying the input type.

Comment: Nice answer.  In the first case, it is referred to as `type witnessing`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't remember hearing this term before.

Comment: You might find this useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24932177/type-witness-in-java-generics.  Personally, on some occasions, I still have problems getting it to work (especially using `thenComparing`).  That's when I use  your second method.